# Adding additional observation in panel data in R

Tags: r, indexing, panel

I am trying to add additional years to my panel data.  Just wondering if you guys have any ideas of quick way of doing it.  Keep in mind my real data is T=6, i=4000.

```
# Here is my input
data = data.frame(time=c(30,40,50,30,40,50,30,40,50), 
                  id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
                  d=c(1,4,7,8,14,2,41,11,61))
# declare panel data individ and time
pd = pdata.frame(data, c("id","time"), drop.index=FALSE)

#this is what I want out... 
data.out = data.frame(time=c(30,40,50,60,30,40,50,60,30,40,50,60), 
                      id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), 
                      d=c(1,4,7,8,9,14,2,41,50,11,61,70))
# declare panel data individ and time
pd.data.out = pdata.frame(data.out, c("id","time"), drop.index=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it... just create new time and id data.frame and merge into it.

```
time = rep(c(unique(as.numeric(as.character(pd$time))),max(as.numeric(as.character(pd$time)))+10), length(unique(pd$id)))
id   = rep( unique(pd$id), each=max(as.numeric(as.character(pd$id)))+1)
data2 = data.frame(time, id)

data.out = merge(data2, pd, all.x=T)
data.out = data.out[with(data.out, order(id,time) ), ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure what you are doing but this might help:

```
data = data.frame(time=c(30,40,50,30,40,50,30,40,50), 
                  id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
                  d=c(1,4,7,8,14,2,41,11,61))
newdata = data.frame(time=c(60,60,60), 
                     id=c(1,2,3), 
                     d=c(9,50,70))
combodata = rbind(data,newdata)
data.out = combodata[order(combodata$id,combodata$time), ]
rownames(data.out) = NULL
```

to produce

```
> data.out
   time id  d
1    30  1  1
2    40  1  4
3    50  1  7
4    60  1  9
5    30  2  8
6    40  2 14
7    50  2  2
8    60  2 50
9    30  3 41
10   40  3 11
11   50  3 61
12   60  3 70
```

and I think this is what you want for `time` and `id`, though `d` is marginally different. If the rows do not need to be ordered then the last three lines of the code can be condensed to

```
data.out = rbind(data,newdata)
```